# Rails 4 image files stored in vendor/images can't be found in the view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I got a custom bootstrap theme up and running with Rails 4, I put the image file at this location:

`/vendor/assets/images/custom_bootstrap_theme/demo/bg01.jpg`

and here's how the index.html.erb consumes this image:

`<img src="/vendor/assets/images/custom_bootstrap_theme/demo/bg11.jpg" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" alt="">`

but bg01.jpg can't be found, could anyone help me with this? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the src to

```
src="/assets/custom_bootstrap_theme/demo/bg11.jpg"
```

And then have a read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks Ingólfur for your reply, still does not work, I got `No route matches [GET] "/assets/custom_bootstrap_theme/demo/bg11.jpg"`

Comment: well, turned out I need to restart the server somehow, all good, thanks again :)